# blink marker and transparent accuracy circle in OSMDroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

1. How to make a blink marker on OSMDroid map? IMHO to redraw it's bitmap (or whole map?) by timer is too expencive.
2. How to make a transparent accuracy circle? Most importantly, how to calculate visible radius by zoom&accuracy?

**Who have examples,** I would have looked, thank you.

p.s. I saw google maps examples, no, I need **osmdroid** working code.

Answer (score 0):

For 2)

- either use [OSMBonusPack Polygon](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_5) with Polygon.pointsAsCircle
- or create your own overlay inspired from osmdroid [DirectedLocationOverlay](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/DirectedLocationOverlay.java)

BTW, 2 questions should lead to 2 SO posts.